# Is it possible to return a SiteMap as a JsonResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

I've got a very simple Action on my Controller that's attempting to return my XmlSiteMap as a JsonResult:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var nodes = SiteMap.Provider.RootNode;
    return new JsonResult() 
        { Data = nodes, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

However, when I call the Action, an InvalidOperationException is thrown:

```
"A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of 
   type 'System.Web.SiteMapNode'."
```

Is there a way to Json serialize a SiteMap, or indeed any object that has children of the same type?

Comment: I haven't used it personally, but I believe JSON.NET (http://www.codeplex.com/Json) is supposed to be able to handle circular dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give JSON.NET a go.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you would accomplish this using Json.NET (http://json.codeplex.com). Note the use of the `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` setting.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public ActionResult Index() {
  JsonSerializerSettings jsSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
  jsSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

  var nodes = SiteMap.Provider.RootNode;
  return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new { Data = nodes }, Formatting.None, jsSettings));
}
```

Comment: +1. Json.NET performs far better than the built-in serializer and gives much more customization options.

Answer (score 1):

One trick you can use when you hit an issue serializing a complex class to a JsonResult is to use LINQ and a `Select()` to project the values to an enumeration over an anonymous type containing just the properties you need from the original complex class.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that having objects of the same time as children should not be a problem but that the problem is that the children reference the parent object and hence you get a circular reference.

It is also possible to implement your own json serializer for this case and explicitly handle the circular reference but that is probably not the best solution.